# List comprehension with if and for loop

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have the following `for` loop and `if` condition. I would like to change it to one line of code using list comprehension of Python. But, I have no idea why it doesn't work as, it says syntax error with '^' pointing at the if statement.

original:

```
for i in range(len(lines)):
        if (lines[i].find('('))!=-1:
            lines[i] = lines[i][0:(lines[i].find('(')-1)]
```

changed to:

```
lines = [[lines[i][0:(lines[i].find('(')-1)]] for (i in range(len(lines))) if ((lines[i].find('('))!=-1)]
```

I just wanted to use the list comprehension methodology which is said to be one of python features. Hope to learn something new, as I don't have programming experience. Thanks for the help, friends!

Comment: You have too many parentheses, some of which are syntactically incorrectly placed. Remove _all_ parentheses, except for those in the function calls.

Comment: For starters, you can try to remove the parentheses around `(i in range(len(lines)))`...

Comment: Fundamentally, though, you probably want to use a plain loop for this so you can keep a reference to `lines[i].find('(')` instead of re-calculating it over and over, which is very inefficient. List comprehensions but don't use them if they make your code unreadable (which you are rapidly approaching) or they force you to be inefficient (as it would in this case)

Comment: hi, i had tried to remove the paraentheses around the for loop and if loop, and it comes down to poping up 'list' object has no attribute 'find', pointing at the if loop

Comment: You can try: `[lines[i][0:(lines[i].find('(')-1)] if (lines[i].find('('))!=-1 else lines[i] for i in range(len(lines))]`

Comment: thanks open-source, the line of code works, so it should include the 'else' for this case.

Comment: thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga as well, i'll take on your suggestion to strive through the balance between readability and performance, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following (*looks little cleaner*):

```
[lines[i][0:lines[i].index('(')-1] if '(' in lines[i] else lines[i] for i in range(len(lines))]
```

So, it says `do trimming if ( is in the line else leave as it is for each line`.

Answer (score 1):

You can go even shorter if you drop `range()` and use `.split()` instead of `.find()`.

```
lines = [line.split('(')[0] for line in lines]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have too many parentheses. 
try this and see if it works.

```
lines = [lines[i][0:lines[i].find('(')-1] for i in range(len(lines)) if lines[i].find('(')!=-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

your changed code can replaced like this

```
apply = lambda line: line[0:line.index('(') - 1]
lines = [apply(line) for line in lines if '(' in line]
```

write code by single line may looks like cool, but it's not readable.

also above code can write single line like this

```
lines = [line[0:line.index('(') - 1] for line in lines if '(' in line]
```

but it's more difficult to read.

**And** your changed code not exactly the same with original.
lines in original code contain string which not have '(' but lines in changed code only contain applied lines.